# Need help finding CSS selector

Tags: html, web-scraping, css-selectors, rvest

Website: https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/985873.A_Game_of_Thrones

There is a "Rating details" button adjacent to book rating. I'm trying to find the css selector to get the text of the entire table, but I was unsuccessful. Can someone help me? No Errors, just not getting the text I wanted

Code:

```
    book_url <- 
    read_html("https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/985873.A_Game_of_Thrones")

    book_url %>%
      html_node("table#rating_distribution") %>%
      html_text()
```

Comment: What errors are you facing? What part doesn't work as expected?

Comment: No Errors, just not getting the text I wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data is within script tag masked by CData. You can regex out the required html and then re-parse with html parser.

```
library(rvest)
library(magrittr)
library(stringr)
library(stringi)

t <- read_html('https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/985873.A_Game_of_Thrones') %>% html_text()
y <- gsub('\n|\\s+',' ',stri_unescape_unicode(t[[1]][1]))
z <- str_match_all(y,'rating_details_tip\'\\), "(.*)", \\{')
tables <- read_html(z[[1]][,2])  %>% html_nodes("table") %>% html_table(fill=T)
table1 <- data.frame(tables[1])  %>% subset(., select=-c(2))
table2 <- data.frame(tables[2])
```

---

[image]

---

I wrote in python first if of interest

```
import requests, re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd

r = requests.get('https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/985873.A_Game_of_Thrones')
p = re.compile(r'rating_details\'\), "(.*)", {')
s = p.findall(r.text)[0].encode().decode('unicode_escape')
s = re.sub(r'\n+\s+|\\','',s )
soup = bs(s, 'lxml')
dfs = pd.read_html(str(soup.select('table')))
print(dfs)
```

Comment: This works. Thank you. Can you explain what stri_unescape_unicode does.

Comment: It unescapes characters. So if there was \\char it would unescape that properly.

Comment: I'm not sure what that means. I recently started learning web scraping. Could you direct me somwhere I could learn more about that.

Comment: https://campus.datacamp.com/courses/string-manipulation-in-r-with-stringr/string-basics?ex=4   You might only need a string escape version rather unicode. See also: https://www.google.com/search?q=string+escape+R&rlz=1C1GCEV_enGB851GB851&oq=string+escape+R&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60j0j69i60j0l2.3320j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8